# Is it possible to install Android Generic System Image (GSI) on QEMU-AARCH64

Tags: android, android-source, qemu, arm64, android-kernel

I am trying to implementing bare metal instance on AWS to install the Android Generic System Image on qemu-aarch64. Is it possible to do that. if yes what is the possibility to connect the installed android through VNC viewer.

Comment: There's two question. 1, How to run Android GSI on qemu-aarch64. 2, How to run VNC server in Android. The first one is the real barrier.